# matplotlib subplots - IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm plotting 8 columns into one figure by using `subplots` function. However, it shows

> "IndexError: too many indices for array"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

df = pd.read_csv('XXXX', encoding='utf-8')

num = 0

for dim in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=1)
    df[dim].plot(ax=axes[num,0])
    plt.xlabel(dim)
    num += 1

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you show `df.head()` in your question, so we have a minimal, complete and verifibiable example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- First, you are defining the `subplots()` inside the for loop which is wrong. You should define it just once outside.
- Second, you need to use `axes[num]` instead of `axes[num, 0]` to refer to a particular subplot since you are having only a single column which is why you get the `> IndexError`. The indexing `axes[num, 0]`, `axes[num, 1]` etc. will work if you have more than 1 column.

---

**Solution**

```
# import commands here 

df = pd.read_csv('XXXX', encoding='utf-8')
num = 0

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=1) # <---moved outside for loop

for dim in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']:
    df[dim].plot(ax=axes[num])
    plt.xlabel(dim)
    num += 1
plt.show()
```

---

Alternative using `enumerate` getting rid of `num` variable

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=1)

for i, dim in enumerate(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']):
    df[dim].plot(ax=axes[i])
    plt.xlabel(dim)
plt.show()
```