# Draw subplots boxplot using python

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, subplot, graph-visualization

I want to draw two parallel box plot in together. For that I used sub plots function in python, below code I used for the that process, but I couldn't get good out put from the code, because its already draw addition two empty graphs, how I remove these empty graphs from the output? Please give ideas for that?

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize = (14,10))
sns.boxplot(x='Heating QC',y='SalePrice',hue='Central Air',  data=df ,ax=axes[0,0])
sns.boxplot(x='Heating',y='SalePrice',hue='Central Air',  data=df ,ax=axes[0,1])
```

**out put**

[image: p]

**After changes got below outputs**

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-543-7dfa6ebf0390> in <module>
      1 f, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize = (14,10))
----> 2 sns.boxplot(x='Heating QC',y='SalePrice',hue='Central Air',  data=df ,ax=axes[0,0])
      3 sns.boxplot(x='Heating',y='SalePrice',hue='Central Air',  data=df ,ax=axes[0,1])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.subplots(2,2)` creates a 2x2 grid of subplots, that's why you've got 4 plots showing.You need to change it to to a `1,2` or `2,1` as you see fit. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: @DavidBuck yes I changed plt.subplots(1,2) then there no any outputs, only give error massage and empty two graph. I add that out put and error massage in question section.

Comment: Your `ax` now need to change to just `axes[0]` and `axes[1]` as you only have a one dimensional array of subplots. That's covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170394/matplotlib-subplots-indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array?rq=1

Comment: @DavidBuck now code is working properly thanks your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create two plots, in which case axes will be a list of 2 elements and use those plot.

Refer the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots).

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (14,10))
sns.boxplot(x='Heating QC',y='SalePrice',hue='Central Air',  data=df, ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot(x='Heating',y='SalePrice',hue='Central Air',  data=df, ax=axes[1])
```